# How can I get the first level category list?

Tags: magento2, category, blocks

I'd like to list all first level categories from inside my custom block. I'd like to get the category names and the URLs.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection $collection */
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('level', 2);
$collection->addIsActiveFilter();
$collection->setStoreId($storeId);
$collection->addUrlRewriteToResult();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
```

Where $storeId is your current store id. You can get it by

```
// \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
$storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
```

**[Update]**

Sample block class:

```
<?php


namespace VendorName\Checkout\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\StateDependentCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Test extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var Category
     */
    private $catalogCategory;

    /**
     * @var StateDependentCollectionFactory
     */
    private $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * Test constructor.
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param Category $catalogCategory
     * @param StateDependentCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        Category $catalogCategory,
        StateDependentCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->catalogCategory = $catalogCategory;
        $this->collectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCategories()
    {
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection $collection */
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('level', 2);
        $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
        $collection->setStoreId($storeId);
        $collection->addUrlRewriteToResult();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');

        $categories = [];
        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            $categories[] = [
                'name' => $category->getName(),
                'url' => $this->catalogCategory->getCategoryUrl($category)
            ];
        }

        return $categories;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, sorry if its a silly question, but how can I get $storeId ?

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: @VibhoreJain please check my Answer, here you can get whole code https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/341568/82670

Comment: @SohelRana thanks but could you elaborate this? How should I create my block class?

Comment: Check the updated answer. You should call $block->getCategories() from your phtml template that is related to this block class

Comment: @SohelRana I tried to use it like this `<?php $block->getCategories(); ?>` but it doesn't show anything. Instead, if I try to use it like this `<?php echo $block->getCategories(); ?>` it shows `Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion`.

Comment: I was able to do it using a `foreach` loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this code**

```
protected $_storeManager;
protected $categoryRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
}

public function getFirstCategoryIds()
{
    $categoryId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
    foreach ($category->getChildrenCategories() as $key => $value) {
        $categoryData = $this->getCategoryData($value->getEntityId());
        print_r($categoryData->getName());
        echo " -- " . $categoryData->getUrl();
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    return $category->getChildrenCategories();
}

public function getCategoryData($id)
{
    return $this->categoryRepository->get($id, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
}
```